# How can I UPDATE a column in a record when that information is the result of a GROUP CONCAT in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, insert-update

I cannot determine if this should be something nested or a JOIN.

Each record has three values from the column `value` across from their name in the column `variable`.

I have a successful GROUP CONCAT that combines them into a single text string.

BUT, I need to UPDATE/INSERT the concat value into another variable=>value pair.

Such as this.   I want each person to have "cityStateZip" in the `value` for `cust_abc'.

I believe it's "INSERT" and not update since none of the records have anything in cust_abc yet.  But, I'm not quite sure if it shouldn't be UPDATE.

| id_member | variable | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | cust_abc | "should show citystatezip" |
| 1234 | cust_a | city |
| 1234 | cust_b | state |
| 1234 | cust_c | zip |

I can't get past the error of having the target table being the same in the SELECT FROM.

I was attempting things like:

```
INSERT INTO smgqg_themes.value (my group concat) WHEN `variable` = "cust_abc"
```

This is the group concat that works fine to make the string:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT
( `value` 
order by case variable 
when 'cust_a' then 1 
when 'cust_b' then 2 else 3 end
SEPARATOR '') 
output
FROM smfqg_themes
WHERE `id_member` IN (1234, 1235, 1236, etc) 
AND `variable`  IN ('cust_a', 'cust_b', 'cust_c')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can INSERT into a the same table you SELECT from in the same SQL statement. I do this all the time.

The syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> (<columns...>)
SELECT ...;
```

The SELECT must return the same columns that you name in the INSERT clause, in the same order.

If you want an existing row to be updated, but still insert a row if one is missing with the 'cust_abc' varible, then you can use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE:

```
INSERT INTO smgqg_themes (id_member, variable, value)
SELECT id_member, 'cust_abc', 
  GROUP_CONCAT(`value` 
    ORDER BY CASE variable 
    WHEN 'cust_a' THEN 1 
    WHEN 'cust_b' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END
    SEPARATOR '') as v
FROM smgqg_themes
WHERE `id_member` IN (1234, 1235, 1236) 
  AND `variable` IN ('cust_a', 'cust_b', 'cust_c')
GROUP BY `id_member`
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE value = VALUES(value);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/OPJQ1ZXF

Comment: I'm not following your syntax clearly.   I cannot insert into id_member or variable--only `value`.  id_member is the primary key, variable is the key and value is the 'value'.  

It has to insert (or update) into `value` when across from it `variable` says "cust_abc" and the id_member is whatever id (or array of id) I give it.

Comment: `id_member` alone can't be the primary key, because you already have multiple rows with the `id_member=1234` in your example. I have included a link to a working dbfiddle demo.

Comment: id_member is the primary and unique key shown in structure.  this is a forum software's 'custom profile fields' table.  you get 3 column:  the id_member, the 'variable' (which is everything from DOB, to address, and more) and the 'value' column.    There are about 50+ entries for each id_member.    My guess is the table was made that way because you can't keep adding and deleting columns when making custom profiles.  Easier to just use the key=>value arrangement?

Comment: I was mistaken.  There are 3 primaries.  id_member, id_theme, and variable.   

I don't understand WHY this solution worked, but I set the entire group concat to a variable:   set @test = 'the whole group concat'.    

Then I used an UPDATE  <table> SET `value` = @test

It updated the record(s) I tested it upon.    But, I don't see why.    

I understand the UPDATE and SET in the same table is kind of like circular references in Excel, but I was taking some data and putting into a "cell" that was isolated in the same table--not part of the calculation.

Comment: You said you wanted to add a new row, because the row with variable 'cust_abc' for a given member doesn't currently exist. That means you need INSERT. The UPDATE statement can only change columns of an existing row.

Comment: Yes, and no which is why I'm here.  I never said I wanted to add a new row.  I was clear about the confusion on Insert / update at the start.   The cust_abc is 'there', it's just empty.  That's where the confusion is.

Comment: Okay, see my updated answer and updated dbfiddle.